# Why does "this" in function statement point to a wrong scope between components?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

- I have a component which is used several times on one page.
- The first line of code in the controller stores "this" in "self" in order to always refer to the right scope.
- When I call a function statement, and I refer to self.content (which is filled with a unique array for all components), self, always refers to the last created component instead of itself.

Why does self.content suddenly refer to a different scope with a function statement (`function validateContent()` instead of `self.validateContent = function () {...}`?

I've cirucmvented this problem by making the function statement an inline one on self `self.validateContent = function() {...}`.

```
component('panel', {
    binding: {
    Content: '<'    // is filled with a unique array per used component.
    },
    controller: function () {

        let self = this;

        self.onSelect() { // is called when an item is selected.

        /* item selection logic */
        function validateContent(); // Validate content after selection.

            self.Content.forEach(/*...*/);
            // Here self is using the scope from the last created component
            // and not the "true" self.
            }
        }

        validateContent();               
    }
});
```

I expected self to refer to the scope of the component, as I see no reason for validateContent() to suddenly refer to another components' scope.

But when outputting self to the console it contains data from the last created component instead of the current one.

Comment: Well to be fair here, `self` and `this` is just superfluous when you are not using `self` in a callback function, you seem to be using it in the exact same context of `this`

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

I'm not sure if I fully undestand what you mean.
I've had several cases in components where `this` refered to a different scope when I tried using it, so I always use the `self` variable to make sure I am refering to the intended scope.

Also, the code as shown above is just the problem isolated, and the actual component contains more code.